# How to show the following infinite series is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am stuck on the following problem:

> I have to show that the following series 
>   is convergent: $$1-\frac{1}{2^2}-\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}-\frac{1}{5^2}-\frac{1}{6^2}+\ldots$$ .

I was trying to make some rearrangement and trying to convert it in alternating series and apply "Leibnitz's test" but failed to do so.
Can someone explain? Thanks and regards to all.

Comment: $|1-\frac{1}{2^2}-\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}-\frac{1}{5^2}-\frac{1}{6^2}+\ldots| \leq 1+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}+\frac{1}{5^2}+\frac{1}{6^2}+\ldots$.

Comment: Be careful about rearranging series in general. By doing so you might change your answer.

Comment: @Luis: absolute convergence is sufficient.

Comment: @Luis: The OP is checking for convergence. So, if the series converges absolutely then it converges conditionally.

Comment: Of course. Absolutely convergent sequences you can rearrange. My point is that he (she) needs to be careful about rearranging in other examples. For example, the alternating harmonic series.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to T.Bongers and Mhenni Benghorbal. I think I have got the trick.

We see that
$$1-\frac{1}{2^2}-\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}-\frac{1}{5^2}-\frac{1}{6^2}+\cdots \le1+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}+\frac{1}{5^2}+\frac{1}{6^2}+ \cdots$$ $$= \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2}$$ and so It is absolutely convergent since $p = 2 > 1$;

Comment: I also forgot to mention, if $a_n \leq c_n$ for all $n$ and $\sum c_n$ converges, so does $\sum a_n$.

Comment: Yes. It was known to me but I failed to foresee it.

Comment: What you wrote does not work, as you have a series where some terms are negative. Comparing the absolute value of the left hand side with the right hand side does not make sense either, as you do not know that the left hand side even has an absolute value until after you show that it converges. Instead, what you need to explain is that the series resulting from replacing each term in your series with its absolute value converges (and it does since, as you say, it is $\sum_k\frac1{k^2}$). This gives absolute convergence and therefore convergence of the series you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

Compare this series to the $p$-series
$$\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2}$$

This is absolutely convergent since $p = 2 > 1$; hence inserting some minus signs won't affect convergence.

Comment: **Remark** If a series $|X|$ is convergent, so is $X$.

Comment: @DonLarynx thank you so much for the input.

Answer (score 1):

In leibnitz test you have to show that $u_n$ satiesfies 2 conditions:

1. $u_{n+1}-u_n<0$
2. $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} u_n=0$

Here $u_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$

It's really easy to show that the 2 tests are valid here.
$$\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}-\frac{1}{n^2}<0$$
and $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{x^2}=0$$
Hence the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{1}{n^2}$ is convergent